# Indirectly access environment variable

Tags: bash, variable

Given I have in a bash script

```
ev=USER
```

How can I get the environment variable value for $USER using ev?

Tried naively doing:

```
echo ${"$"$ev}
```

which results in bad substitution.

I'd expect to get back whatever the value of $USER is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By using an indirect expansion (also sometimes called "variable indirection"),

```
ev=USER
printf '%s\n' "${!ev}"
```

This is described in the `bash` (5.0) manual, in the section titled "Parameter Expansion".

Or, by making `ev` a name reference (requires `bash` 4.3+),

```
declare -n ev=USER
printf '%s\n' "$ev"
```

This is described in the `bash` (5.0) manual, just *before* the section called "Positional Parameters".

Comment: Perfect thanks ... env_val="${!ev}"

Answer (score 6):

If it's only about *environment* variables, as opposed to shell variables, then on most systems, you can use:

```
printenv -- "$ev"
```

For shell variables, with any Bourne-like shell, you can do:

```
eval 'printf "%s\n" "${'"$ev"}'}"'
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${(P)ev}"
```

Or with `bash`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${!ev}"
```

All 3 are arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities if the content of `$ev` is not under your control.

Answer (score 2):

You can also evaluate the command after the vale for `$ev` has been substituted:

```
eval echo "$"$ev
```

The part `"$"$ev` resolves to `$USER` so `eval` executes `echo $USER`.